# How to say, "Pride makes other people feel bad about themselves"?

Tags: traduction

I would like to write this sentence in French. So far, I have what Google Translate gives me.

> Pride makes other people feel bad about themselves.
>
> [La fierté fait que les autres se sentent mal dans leur peau.](https://translate.google.com/#en/fr/Pride%20makes%20other%20people%20feel%20bad%20about%20themselves.)

I'm not quite sure "La fierté" is the most appropriate word for pride, as I intend to use "pride" with a negative connotation (cf. Pr. 16:18 "L'arrogance précède la ruine...")

Which word would be better for my sentence? La fierté or L'arrogance? In English, there's a marked difference between pride and arrogance, no matter the connotation.

Lastly, I realize that Google Translate uses the idiom, "to feel bad in one's own skin". Is this a natural translation of my English sentence? What would be your preferred translation?

Comment: *Etre mal dans sa peau* is indeed a bit vague, it may mean to feel confused, to feel guilty, to feel embarrassed, depending on the context. Maybe you could clarify a bit what you mean ? I understand that you mean that pride makes other people have a lower self-esteem, am I right ? As for *pride*, *fierté* has indeed a positive connotation. You may want to use *orgueil*, which is the name of the capital sin named *pride* in English.

Answer (score 3):

You could say "l'orgueil" which has a negative connotation.
I would say that "Se sentir mal dans sa peau" generally refers to a long lasting feeling (typically followed by "these days", or even a personality trait in "être mal dans sa peau"), so if you want to express a temporary feeling, this is not the most appropriate. Maybe "se sentir dévalorisé" would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Je ne vois pas de traduction naturelle (je veux dire simple) de votre phrase.
Le problème est que la phrase d'origine est assez éloignée de ce qui serait naturel en français.

La question est de traduire "Pride make the others feel bad about themselves".
Le verbe à choisir dépend du reste de la phrase, 
donc je propose de ne pas trop s'y arrêter.
Il reste donc trois idées :
 - *Pride*
 - *the others*
 - *feel bad about themselves*

D'abord, pour *Pride*, la difficulté n'est pas tant de choisir un mot moins positif que "fierté"
(vous en donnez vous-même "arrogance", et on vous a suggéré orgueil)
que le fait que *pride* flotte sans personne pour l'éprouver.
Si vous traduisez mot-à-mot, "l'orgueil fait que les autres se sentent mal dans leur peau", on croirait presque que vous dites que les autres se sentent mal dans leur peau à cause de **leur** orgueil (*Due to their pride, the others feel bad about themselves*) ce qui est à peu près le contraire de ce que vous voulez dire.

Il faudrait donc par exemple utiliser un adjectif possessif : 
Mon/Ton/Son/Notre... orgueil.
Si vous voulez garder la notion de vérité générale, 
soit vous pouvez utiliser "notre" où le nous désigne en quelque sorte l'humanité en général pour désigner l'orgueil de chacun d'entre nous,
soit vous pouvez utiliser une autre formulation "l'orgueil des uns" ce qui a un côté proverbial et est un peu plus soutenu.

Ensuite, pour *the others*, il faut faire attention à ce que 
"les autres" peut avoir la signification de *certains* autres. On peut utiliser "autrui" pour éviter ce biais, ou éliminer la dépendance
envers les autres en utilisant l'adverbe "toujours".
On peut aussi utiliser "les autres" tout simplement, selon le contexte.

Passons enfin à "feel bad about themselves".
Toute la difficulté est qu'en français il n'y a pas d'expression pour dire
quelque chose d'aussi général imprécis que "feel bad about themselves". Pourquoi se sentent-ils mal ? Peut-être qu'ils sont humiliés, peut-être qu'ils se sentent coupables ? Ils peuvent aussi être déprimés, se sentir mal à l'aise. J'éviterais "mal dans leur peau" car c'est quelque chose de long terme (on n'est pas mal dans sa peau pendant 5 minutes). Il faut savoir ce qu'on veut exprimer exactement pour terminer la traduction.

Je donne quelques possibilités :

> Notre orgueil humilie toujours les autres.
>
> Notre orgueil est une humiliation pour autrui.
>
> L'orgueil des uns déprime les autres.
>
> Ton orgueil met les autres mal à l'aise.
>
> L'orgueil des uns provoque la jalousie des autres.

Bien entendu, il est possible de les mélanger pour en obtenir encore d'autres.

Comment: Bonne explication. Pour un ton "proverbial", j'opterais pour "_L'orgueil des uns fait la honte des autres_"